# COM object with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is either not valid or not registered

Tags: asp.net, ms-office

In my application there is a functionality to show an excel sheet.Due to some reason we need to uninstall Microsoft Office.
Now the above functionality is not working and I am getting following error.

**COM object with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is either not valid or not registered.**

Any Ideas how do I resolve this without re-installing Microsoft Office?

Answer (score 4):

Given that you've uninstalled Office the COM object you need *will* be unregistered.

The only way is to either reinstall Office or install the [Office Tools Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178739.aspx)

Comment: my application is on vs2003 so I need  office tools runtime compatible to this version.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to rewrite your code that processes Excel spreadsheets without using Office automation then. There's plenty of library suggestions here

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)

That question is for creation but most (if not all!) of these will read too.